# Microsoft Visual Studio 2019: Unable to locate .NET Core SDK

Tags: visual-studio, azure

When I try to create an Azure Timer Function in a Function App in Visual Studio Code 2019, I get the following error:

> Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed and
> that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the
> installed version

However, when I look in my installed programs, it does show that the .NET Core SDK is installed:
[image]

Strangely enough though, when I search for the SDK in the command line (with the command `dotnet --info`)... nothing appears:
[image]

It looks like the Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.302 is **installed**, but it cannot be located by the system.

Comment: What is the version specified in `global.json` ?

Comment: @Tony I can't seem to find global.json. I searched the entire disk for it...

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1431833/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-locate-net-core-sdk): maybe you are missing a specific version of the SDK (x86 or x64) or you just wanna try a re-installation of the SDK. [Link to .NET Core download-page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/). Another thing you could check is whether C:\Program Files\dotnet\ is in the PATH variables of your system.

Answer (score 0):

Add environment variable using following steps

If your operating system is windows 10,
Right click "**This PC**" -> **Properties**
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAySL.png)

Then click "**Advance system settings**" and click "**Environment Variable**" button as follow

[Environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEebX.png)

Then select the path and click **Edit** button
[User Variables for Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuU9N.png)

For the above error you have to add dotnet location.
Click **New** and add dotnet file path.
C:\Program Files\dotnet

[File path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAytE.png)